Check duplicated field values from WSO2 MI
I have a json input to the wso2 micro integrator.
I want to check, my input payload has duplicated language values.
Ex:
{
    "category": "test-category",
    "displayNames": [
        {
            "language": "en",
            "displayName": "sample",
            "description": "this is a sample"
        }, {
            "language": "de",
            "displayName": "german",
            "description": "this is a german description"
        },
        {
            "language": "en",
            "displayName": "new text",
            "description": "this is a new text"
        }
    ]
}

Above json has duplicated language with "en" value.
First I tried to achieve this using a json schema. But we cannot use json schema to validate duplicates.
How can I do that?

If you know the languages that can comein, you can do something like below.
<filter xpath="count(//displayNames[language = 'en']) > 1 or count(//displayNames[language = 'de']) > 1">
    <then>
        <log>
            <property name="MSG" value="Duplicate language values"/>
        </log>
    </then>
    <else/>
</filter>

Or else you can do something like below.
<property name="langs" scope="default" type="STRING" value=""/>
<foreach expression="json-eval($.displayNames)">
    <sequence>
        <filter xpath="contains($ctx:langs, //language/text())">
                <then>
                    <log>
                        <property name="MSG" value="Duplicate language values"/>
                    </log>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <property expression="concat($ctx:langs, ',', //language/text())" name="langs" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                </else>
            </filter>
    </sequence>
</foreach>

